# how to write a loop to data frame without over writing previous value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

basically i want the program to run over rows in dataframes
the problem is when writing each processing value of each row into the csv file, the values will be duplicated across all rows and the last row result in the loop will overwrite the rest values 
this is my code:

```
#Import the libraries
from textblob import TextBlob

import pandas as pd


read=pd.read_csv('HR.csv',delimiter=',',skip_blank_lines=False,skiprows=1,names=['Comments','Score','Sentiment'])
data=pd.DataFrame(read)


for row in data.itertuples():

        rw=str(row)
        obj = TextBlob(rw)


        sentiment=obj.sentiment.polarity

        print(sentiment)

        data['Score']=sentiment



        data.to_csv('HR12.csv',index=False,mode='a')



        if sentiment == 0:
            s='Neutral'
            data['Sentiment']='Neutral'

            data.to_csv('HR12.csv',index=False)


        elif sentiment > 0:
            s='Positive'
            data['Sentiment']='Positive'

            data.to_csv('HR12.csv',index=False)



        else:
            s='Negative'
            data['Sentiment']='Negative'
            data.to_csv('HR12.csv',index=False)
```

so instead of getting each sentiment for each row entered in my output file, i am getting the only the last value for the whole dataframe 
for example :
comment,score,sentiment
d1,1,positive
d2,1,positive
d3,1,positive
etc..

instead of 
comment,score,sentiment
d1,-1,negative
d2,1,positive
d3,1,positive
etc..

Answer (score 2):

you should using .apply() method to iterate over rows via lambda.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd

def get_sent(comment):
   score = TextBlob(comment).sentiment.polarity
   if score == 0:
       return 'Nuetral'
   elif score > 0:
       return 'Positive'
   else:
       return 'Negative'

data = pd.read_csv('HR.csv', delimiter=',', skip_blank_lines=False, skiprows=1, names['Comments','Score','Sentiment'])

data['sentiment'] = data.apply(lambda x: get_sent(x['comments']))

data.to_csv('HR12.csv',index=False)
```

Let me know if this helps!